# How to get Json object in Rest Services?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, rest

I am new to Rest Services. I am passing Json object using Post method but i am not able to get the values of the class properties.

my code is like below

```
    function SaveBook() {
        var bookData = { "ISDCode": "TestISD", 
                "retailerCode":"RT148",
                 "count":"2",
                 "salesdata":[
                  {
                    "Serial":"3544334444",
                    "CustomerPhone":"98234234234",
                    "CustomerName":"Name1",
                    "CustomerInfoID":"1",
                    "TimeStamp":"22-May-14",
                    "Latitude":"10.3456",
                    "Longitude":"8.3453"
                   },
                   { 
                    "Serial":"35324432324",
                    "CustomerPhone":"9824322333333",
                    "CustomerName":"Name2",
                    "CustomerInfoID":"2",
                    "TimeStamp":"21-May-14",
                    "Latitude":"10.3344",
                    "Longitude":"8.9564"
                    }]
                    }

         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "http://localhost/API/Service.svc/PostTertiarySales",
             data: JSON.stringify(bookData),

             contentType: "application/json",
             dataType: "json",
             //processData: true,
             success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
                 alert("success..." + data);
             },
             error: function (xhr) {
                 alert(xhr.responseText);
             }
         });
     }
     </script>
```

In Iservice.cs
[DataContract]
        public class TertiarySales
        {
            [DataMember]
            public string ISDCode { get; set; }

```
        [DataMember]
        public string retailerCode { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string count { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public List<WCFlib.CompositeType.TertiaryData> salesdata { get; set; }

    }
    [DataContract]
    public class TertiaryData
    {
        public string Serial { get; set; }
        public string CustomerPhone { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public Int32 CustomerInfoID { get; set; }
        public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
        public double Latitude { get; set; }
        public double Longitude { get; set; }

        public TertiaryData(string Serial, string CustomerPhone, string CustomerName, Int32 CustomerInfoID, DateTime TimeStamp, double Latitude, double Longitude)
        {
            this.Serial = Serial;
            this.CustomerPhone = CustomerPhone;
            this.CustomerName = CustomerName;
            this.CustomerInfoID = CustomerInfoID;
            this.TimeStamp = TimeStamp;
            this.Latitude = Latitude;
            this.Longitude = Longitude;
        }

    }
```

[OperationContract]

```
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "PostTertiarySales",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST")]
    bool PostTertiarySales(WCFlib.CompositeType.TertiarySales data);
```

in Service.cs

public bool PostTertiarySales(WCFlib.CompositeType.TertiarySales data)
        {

```
         return true;
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: not getting the values of salesdata in the "data" like i am getting Serial=null

Comment: You mean you are not getting the `TertiaryData` class properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decorate `[DataMember]` for the TertiaryData class properties as well

```
[DataContract]
public class TertiaryData
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Serial { get; set; }
    ...
}
```